# how to access component closure in Angular 2 written in ES5?

Tags: angular, closures

I'm using ES5 to write Angular 2, and in one of my components I have this JavaScript code:

```
app.user = ng.core.Component({
    selector: 'user',
    templateUrl: '/html/account/user'
}).Class({
    constructor: function () {
        this.getUserInfo();
    },
    getUserInfo: function () {
        this.progress = true;
        this.user = app.http.get('/accountsUser/info', {withCredentials: true}).toPromise().then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            this.progress = false;
        });
    }
});
```

However, in my then function, I can't access this property, because it's undefined.
in Angular 1, we would use $scope as a global variable throughout our controller declaration function. Here in our Class definition object, we can't have a global variable to use in the callback. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Change `function (response)` with `(response)=>`

So it will look like

```
this.user = app.http.get('/accountsUser/info', {withCredentials: true}).toPromise()
   .then( (response)=> {
     console.log(response);
     this.progress = false;
});
```